# Перенаправление фрейма с помощью ссылки

Tags: javascript

Например, этот скрипт:

`<SCRIPT>parent.frames._location.document.location.href='url'</SCRIPT>`

Перенаправляет фрейм _location на заданную url. А как сделать ссылку, чтоб она перенаправляла в том же духе? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вот так ?

```
<a href="javascript:parent.frames._location.document.location.href='url';">Text</a>
```

Comment: Понял, спс, работает))